# How can I conjugate verbs that are, and have been, going on habitually?

Tags: traducción, verbos, tiempos-verbales

I want to translate the following sentence:

> Spanish is one of the most spoken languages in the world.

After writing it, I realized it was a bit unnatural (I'd rather say it in terms of *speakers*), but I also realized that it posed me with an interesting question. How do I conjugate *spoken* in this sentence?

The first tense that comes to mind for *spoken* is the indicative imperfect, where the pronoun would be *them*. The reason is that the indicative imperfect is used for habitual action; however, it is habitual action only in the past (according to [this explanation](https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/spanish-imperfect-tense-forms) on Spanishdict).

In the example sentence, the verb is an habitual action both in the past, present and likely, in the future (if that matters). So, what would the right translation be? My best attempt, using the indicative imperfect tense, is this:

> Español es una de las más hablaban idiomas del mundo.

Feel free to correct anything said here, so long as any answer provides the answer to how one conjugates habitual actions from the past to present. I found [this article](https://www.spanishschoolvalencia.com/how-to-talk-about-habits/) on the matter, but the tense it spoke of seemed inapplicable, since it conjugated the habitual action by way of an auxiliary verb with a function like that of *normally*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are making a mistake, in the example sentence, *spoken* is not a verbal tense associated with a personal pronoun, but a participle. The correct translation would be to replace it with the participle in Spanish:

> El Español es uno de los idiomas más **hablados** del mundo

Answer (score 5):

Creo que estás confundiendo algunos conceptos sobre los verbos. Vamos a poner en claro algunas cosas:

> In the example sentence, the verb is an habitual action both in the past, present and likely, in the future (if that matters)

Esto no es cierto, el verbo de la oración es ‘is’, y está refiriendo únicamente al *presente*. En ningún momento se da a entender que trate sobre el pasado ni tampoco sobre el futuro.

Por otro lado, *spoken* está jugando el rol de adejtivo y es por eso hay que usar el participio. Esto funciona igual que en el inglés. La traducción correcta de dicha palabra es *hablado(s)*. Por lo tanto:

> ...where the pronoun would be *them*

Tampoco es cierto. Otra vez, *spoken* es un adjetivo. No es un verbo en este caso, por lo tanto el pronombre asociado no es ‘ellos’ [*them*]. En todo caso, a lo que está asociado es al sustantivo ‘idiomas’ [*languages*].

El artículo en ‘español’ no se puede omitir. Por lo que quedaría:

> El español es uno de los idiomas más hablados del mundo.

Que solamente hace referencia al tiempo presente y no indica nada sobre el pasado.

Pero, si entendí bien tu pregunta, estás buscando la forma de expresar algo que ocurrió en el pasado y que también sigue sucediendo en el presente. En otras palabras, un equivalente al **present perfect** es en lo que consistiría la respuesta que debería darte. Por desgracia, no existe algo equivalente en castellano. Algunos van a decirte que el *pretérito compuesto* es una buena traducción, pero este tiempo sólo refiere gramaticalmente al pasado. Es decir, una posibilidad sería quizá:

> El español **ha sido** uno de los idiomas más hablados del mundo.

Si se cuenta con el contexto suficiente esta traducción podría funcionar y el verbo sería interpretado como uno que refiere al pasado y presente. Es lo que sucede en este caso debido al contenido de la oración. Pero no es lo que suele pasar, y lo más probable que ocurra con otras frases es que sean entendidas como acontecimientos sólo del pasado.

Por lo tanto, frente a este potencial inconveineite te ofrezco dos estrategias posibles:

- **Usar dos verbos, uno en pasado y otro en presente**. Es la traducción más directa y explícita posible para lo que estás buscando:

> El español **fue, y es,** [*has been*] uno de los idiomas más hablados del mundo.

> El español **fue, y sigue siendo,** [*has been*] uno de los idiomas más hablados del mundo.

- **Agregar adverbios de tiempo apropiados**. En este caso la oración sigue siendo gramaticalmente del pasado pero los adverbios y el contexto hacen que se entienda que sigue ocurriendo en el presente:

> **Siempre y hasta el día de hoy**, el español **ha sido** uno de los idiomas más hablados del mundo.

> **Desde su auge**, el español **siempre ha sido** uno de los idiomas más hablados del mundo.

Esta segunda estrategia es más rebuscada que la primera, pero en mi opinión queda mucho mejor y suena más natural.

Comment: Extremadamente buena respuesta, ojalá pudiera darle más que un +1